# How to write a query to find all tables in a db that have a specific column name

Tags: metadata

I've got a database with about 100 tables and I need to build a join query to get specific data from two of them.  I know one but not the other.  Basically I need something like:

`select <tables> from <database> where exists table.column name;`

How can I do this?

Comment: My answer assumed SQL Server.  Is that the RDBMS you're working with?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Using `information_schema`

This is the standards-compliant cross-RDBMS way to do it.

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE column_name = '<your column name>';
```

You can see this documented

- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html)
- [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql)
- [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Why not to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, by our very own @AaronBertrand (https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Comment: @ThomasStringer I agree but the OP has not tagged the question with any dbms tag.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Use a real database, right off the bat PostgreSQL has supported Identity Columns in the `information_schema.columns` since 2006. A full decade before it even implemented them. If Microsoft SQL doesn't support the standard, perhaps we should be looking at nagging them. Others do.

Comment: note: this also returns views columns so add to check for table type

Answer (score 5):

For IBM DB2 you would use the following:

```
select tabschema,tabname from syscat.columns where colname = 'COLUMN_NAME'
```

Note that in DB2, column names will be in upper case **unless** they were defined inside of double quotes with something other than upper case. Then you have to supply the **exact** casing of the column name as well.

Comment: If the column where defined using quotes (which should be avoided), you can use UPPER or UCASE function to transform the colname to upper case: `WHERE UPPER(colname) =  'COLUMN_NAME'`.

Answer (score 3):

The below query should give you what you're looking for:

```
use YourDatabase;
go

select
    object_schema_name(t.object_id) + '.' + t.name as table_name,
    c.name as column_name
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c
on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name like '%ColumnSearchText%';
```

If you're looking for columns of an exact name, just replace the `WHERE` clause with:

```
where c.name = 'ColumnSearchText';
```

Answer (score 0):

in Teradata 15:

```
SELECT DATABASENAME||'.'||TABLENAME AS FULL_TABLENAME,
COUNT(1) AS NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
FROM DBC.COLUMNSV
WHERE 1 = 1
AND COLUMNNAME LIKE '%<YOUR COLUMNNAME HERE>%'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle sql / plsql:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name='yourcolumnname';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM _v_sys_columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME='$COLUMN_NAME'
```

Please pass the column name to this variable: `$COLUMN_NAME`

Answer (score -3):

## //**Select the Particular table:**

```
SYNTAX:
       SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME='VALUE';
EXAMPLE:
       SELECT PERSON_NAME FROM PERSON WHERE PERSON_ID=1;
```

Comment: You probably misread the OP's question, your answer does not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -3):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN 
( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM syscolumns 
    WHERE name = 'EXACT_COLUMN_NAME_TO_SEARCH'
)
```