# Find in what table I can find multiple collumns

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, data-dictionary, catalog-views

I am trying to write a query that will show me the tables that contains all the following columns: *ProductGroup*, *ProductClass* and *ProductID*.

But I am not very successful at it. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a query to find all tables in a db that have a specific column name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44785/how-to-write-a-query-to-find-all-tables-in-a-db-that-have-a-specific-column-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Oracle:**

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM ALL_IND_COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('ProductGroup', 'ProductClass', 'ProductID')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

**For MS SQL and others:**

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('ProductGroup', 'ProductClass', 'ProductID')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: There's no INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Oracle.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you call "the entire db".

If it really is the database, then you'd query `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`, connected as user who has access to that view (such as SYS, if you don't have any other):

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select owner, table_name from dba_tab_columns where column_name = 'EMPNO';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SCOTT                          EMP
SCOTT                          TEST
```

If you want to check all tables you have access to, query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`:

```
SQL> connect scott@pdb1
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'EMPNO';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SCOTT                          EMP
SCOTT                          TEST
```

If you want to see tables that belong to your schema, then it is `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` (in some DBMS, they call it the "database"; in Oracle, that's just a "schema" - that's why I asked what the "database" means to you):

```
SQL> select table_name from user_tab_columns where column_name = 'EMPNO';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
EMP
TEST

SQL>
```